# How to map between a notion user email and auth token?

Tags: database, api, endpoint, notion-api

I am implementing a notion integration for my Webapp, and I am using the public integration method. I can successfully implement that, after the completion of the authorization process, I am getting a data object as a response from notion server which looks something like this:

```
data: {
   access_token: 'secret_nNxpaB6dG03j29cxHfCqkB2yLByIet1jaAIRr7UYAzE',
   workspace_name: 'Mike's Notion',
   bot_id: '45fcdb55-0zzz-zzz0-7654-8b6be4789906'
}
```

But, I need to save this access_token for a particular user against his email, so that the user could use this access_token to access his workspace, and here there is no field for user email or user name or anything like this, so how to save this in the database?

Answer (score 1):

The integrations used for Notion are at the workspace level. They are not tied to a user.